# React, the state is triggered for all blocks containing the style, but it needs for only one

Tags: reactjs, transform

```
class Article extends React.Component{  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {showIncreaced: false}
    }

    increase = () => {
        this.setState({showIncreaced: !this.state.showIncreaced})
    }

    render(){   
        const TipStyle={                        
                marginBottom: '10px'
    }

    const ImgStyle={
        width: '20vw',
        marginRight: '0.5vw',
        marginLeft: '0.5vw',
        transform: this.state.showIncreaced ? 'scale(1.5, 1.5)' : 'scale(1, 1)'
}

    return(                     
        <div style={TipStyle}>                      
          <h2 style={{marginBottom: '1px'}}>{this.props.name}</h2>
          <div>
              <img style={ImgStyle} src={this.props.img1} onMouseOver={this.increase} onMouseOut={this.increase}/>
              <img style={ImgStyle} src={this.props.img2} onMouseOver={this.increase} onMouseOut={this.increase}/>
              <img style={ImgStyle} src={this.props.img3} onMouseOver={this.increase} onMouseOut={this.increase}/>                              
          </div>
        </div>                  
  ); 
 }
}
```

When hovering over a picture (for example img1) should increase only img1. But all img with style={ImgStyle} increase. What wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/k1j5se0u/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna to make only one of them increasing in size when hovering, you need to use ids. I've changed a bit your sample using id instead of boolean, and with additional improvenets:

```
class Article extends React.Component{  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {showIncreaced: null}

    this.getImgStyle = this.getImgStyle.bind(this);
    this.increase = this.increase.bind(this);
    }

    increase (incId) {
        this.setState({showIncreaced: incId})
    }

  getImgStyle (id) {
    return {
      width: '20vw',
      marginRight: '0.5vw',
      marginLeft: '0.5vw',
      transform: this.state.showIncreaced === id ? 'scale(1.5, 1.5)' : 'scale(1, 1)'
    };
  }

    render(){   
        const TipStyle={                        
                marginBottom: '10px'
        }

    return(                     
        <div style={TipStyle}>                      
          <h2 style={{marginBottom: '1px'}}>{this.props.name}</h2>
          <div>
        {[1,2,3].map((id) => {
            return <img style={this.getImgStyle(id)} src={this.props[`img${id}`]} onMouseOver={this.increase.bind(this, id)} onMouseOut={this.increase} />
        })}                         
          </div>
        </div>                  
); 
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k1j5se0u/36/

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling the increased state variable for each image and then applying it to all of your images in the styling. You need a way to differentiate between the hover events on the images so you can apply the styles correctly.

So you should have a default image style, and then another image style with the modified attributes and only apply that to a single image.